# Why do you have to submit twice before jQuery Validate submitHandler is triggered?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-validate

I have a situation where validating a HTML form with jQuery Validation Plugin 1.9.0. (I'm using jQuery 1.6.4). 
If the form is filled out correctly after the page is loaded the validation takes place on submit. The validation gives a success message, but it doesn't trigger the submitHandler. 
It only triggers the submitHandler if you press the submit button again.

I created a simulation on http://jsfiddle.net/peterph/Hv3xz/1/ to illustrate the problem.
Can anyone tell me how I can fix this problem?

```
<form method="post" id="form">
    <input id="E_Mail" name="E_mail" title="E_mail" required="required" /><br />
    <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Send"/>
</form>

<script>
    jQuery(function($) {
        $("#form").submit(function(e) {
            var $form = $(this);
            alert('Start Validation');
            $form.validate({
                debug: false,
                focusInvalid: false,
                onfocusout: false,
                onkeyup: false,
                onclick: false,
                rules:
                {
                    E_mail: {required:true, email:true },
                },
                success: function(label) {
                    alert('succes:' + label);
                },
                submitHandler: function(form){
                    alert('start submitHandler');
                    postContent('test');
                    alert('end submitHandler');
                },
                invalidHandler: function(form, validator) {
                    alert('invalidHandler');
                },
            }).form();
            alert('end Validation');
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    });

    function postContent(postData){
        alert('postcontent: ' + postData);
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`validate` is not called until you submit the form. The first time you hit `submit`, validate has not been applied to the form. The second time it has.

You should move the call to `validate` outside of the `submit` handler:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $("#form").validate({
        debug: false,
        focusInvalid: false,
        onfocusout: false,
        onkeyup: false,
        onclick: false,
        rules:
        {
            E_mail: {required:true, email:true },
        },
        success: function(label) {
            alert('succes:' + label);
        },
        submitHandler: function(form){
            alert('start submitHandler');
            postContent('test');
            alert('end submitHandler');
        },
        invalidHandler: function(form, validator) {
            alert('invalidHandler');
        },
    });
});
```

And everything should work fine.

**Updated Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/8r47E/