# Jquery Validation : Submit button have to be clicked twice for form submission (fire fox)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, validation, firefox

I am using `jquery validation plugin` for **US ZIPCODE CHECK** ,its working fine,
but I have to **push the submit button TWICE** to get the form submitted,

**Note :** if I press enter that it submits the form properly, but it doesnt work with `click event`

I **already have checked** this stackoverflow answers but they didnt helped me out

[Why do you have to submit twice before jQuery Validate submitHandler is triggered?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9838054/why-do-you-have-to-submit-twice-before-jquery-validate-submithandler-is-triggere)

[jquery validate need to click submit twice to submit form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20496840/jquery-validate-need-to-click-submit-twice-to-submit-form)

[jQuery using .on and .validate must submit form twice to validate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15671712/jquery-using-on-and-validate-must-submit-form-twice-to-validate)

Below is my Javascript code

```
var ans;
$(document).ready(function(e)
        {
           jQuery.validator.addMethod("zipcode", function(e)
            {
               $.ajax(
                        {
                            url: "http://zip.elevenbasetwo.com",
                            cache: false,
                            async: false,
                            dataType: "json",
                            type: "GET",
                            data: "zip=" + $("#zip").val(),
                            success: function()
                            {
                                ans = true;
                            },
                            complete: function()
                            {
                                ans = true;
                            },
                            error: function()
                            {
                                ans = false;
                            }
                        }
                );
                return ans;
            });
            $("#register-form2").validate({
                debug: true,
                onkeyup: false,
                rules: {
                    zip: {
                        required: true,
                        zipcode: true,
                        minlength: 5
                    },
                    email: {
                        required: true,
                        email: true
                    }
                },
                messages: {
                    zip: {
                        required: "Please enter a USA zip code",
                        zipcode: "Please enter a valid USA zip code"
                    },
                    //  zip: "Please enter a valid USA zip code.",
                    email: "Please enter a valid email address."
                },
                submitHandler: function(form)
                {
                    alert('hi');
                    form.submit();
                }
            });
        });
```

Please mark that **if I dont use ajax function in my custom method** than it just works fine, but i am not able to solve it.

below is my `HTML code`

```
<form action="<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post" class="wpcf7-form" id="register-form2" novalidate>
<input name="email" required id="email" type="text" placeholder="Email*">
<input type="text" name="zip" id="zip" required size="40" maxlength="15" placeholder="Zip code* (USA only)">
<input name="Form_submit" class="btn btn-primary wpcf7-form-control  wpcf7-submit" id="Submit" value="Sign-up" type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Looks like you're returning `ans` in your `zipcode` function before it's actually assigned. Move `return` statement inside callbacks.

Comment: @IlyaLuzyanin thanks for the reply.. i already tried putting `return values in ajax success and error callbacks`... but that doesnt return any value :(

Comment: Oops, nevermind, that was a stupid idea (it won't return nothing, I agree). Is ajax function fired both times? What are the values of `ans` each time?

Comment: yeah.. ajax is fired all the times, and returns perfect values, eg if `invalid zipcode than it return false, and for valid it returns true`..

Comment: Maybe restructure this a little bit, like in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13203690/2571926? They're using `remote` instead of ajax requests.

Comment: try removing debug: true, onkeyup: false from validator

Comment: @IlyaLuzyanin thanks. i already tried it.. it also doesnt let the form submit,, and remote call only works once, than i have to reload the page...

Comment: @zaw I already done but no success :(...

Comment: I just tried on fiddle its working fine? http://jsfiddle.net/9jr5D/

Comment: @zaw yeah i checked your fiddle.. but still the same problem.. on first click it doesnt submit the form... which browser you are using?? I am on firefox

Comment: @zaw yeah.. I checked on chrome. its working good on chrome.. but not in firefox...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/9jr5D/1/ updated and tested on firefox its working for me..

Comment: @zaw for me it doesnt works on the first click. I always have to click twice...